# ImageMagick convert command misses frames

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I am using 'convert' to make animated gifs with some png images I have generated.

If these images are small, then all works fine. I did

```
convert  -delay 3  -loop 0  animation-small-png-1/*  animation-small-1.gif
```

The generated gif works, see it with this post, it's the one with the big circle.

But if I take the big images and I do

```
convert  -delay 3  -loop 0  animation-small-png-2/*  animation-small-2.gif
```

Then the generated gif doesn't work fine, see it with this post : it's the one with the little circle, the size of this circle jumps one time by animation cycle. That is not normal, see please the previous gif file.

Can someone help me ?

[image: animation-small-1]

[image: animation-small-2]

[images 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qej92ej946e7hjr/animation-small-png-1.tar.gz?dl=0)

[images 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rza6vu6mh389ocn/animation-small-png-2.tar.gz?dl=0)

Comment: Are you sure your directories have the proper number of frames?  Zip your directory holding the small images and post that zip file so others can test with it.

Comment: I am sure for the number of frames. I would like to upload the two zip files but I don't find the uploading function.

Comment: Post them to some free hosting service and put the URLs in a comment or your original post

Comment: That's done, the links are here.

Answer (score 0):

Your Imagemagick command works fine for me on IM 6.9.12-70 Q16 Mac OSX Monterey and libpng 1.6.38

```
convert  -delay 3  animation-small-png-2/*  -loop 0  animation-small-2.gif
```

[image]

What is your Imagemagick version and platform/OS?  What is your version of libpng? Do you have enough space in your /tmp directory?  Are there left-over Imagemagick files there that you can delete?

My guess was that your /tmp directory got too full and could not handle any more files during your processing of the animation.

Comment: OS debian 11.6 ; ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 ; libpng 1.6.37 ; /tmp have 92k inside. It's no png file in /tmp

Comment: Try upgrading Imagemagick and/or libpng.